# Using lodash to get the closest next value of a prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects, each with non correlative ids.

I would like to know if it is possbile, given an integer, to find the next closest id value object.

Example

```
const array = [{id: 4}, {id: 10}, {id: 15}]
```

given any value `x`, if `10 < x <= 15`, it should return `15`

given any value `x`, if `4 < x <= 10` , it should return `10`

and so on.

Thank you

Comment: probably have to loop over all the values once and check if there is a closer one for each value, or order the list first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your array is not sorted, and you don't want to use the `.sort` method (for example: maybe because you don't want to mutate your array), you can use `.reduce` to find the best result:

```js
const array = [{id: 4}, {id: 10}, {id: 20}, {id: 15}]

function findClosest(x) {
    return array.reduce((best, current) => {
        return (current.id >= x && (!best || current.id < best.id))
            ? current
            : best;
    }, undefined);
}

console.log(findClosest(11))
console.log(findClosest(16))
```

Answer (score 3):

If every time you want the higher one, you can check this.

Find that item which `id` is higher than your `x`. Also I think that you need first to sort your array based on `id`, to not have any issues with unsorted ones.

```js
const x = 5;
const array = [{id: 4}, {id: 10}, {id: 15}];

const max = array.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
                 .find(item => item.id > x);

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the array is sorted by `id` value, you can use `Array.find()` to find a the 1st `id` that is greater or equal to `x`:

```js
const array = [{id: 4}, {id: 10}, {id: 15}]

const findClosestId = (x) => (array.find(({ id }) => x <= id) || {}).id


console.log(findClosestId(11)); // 15
console.log(findClosestId(6)); // 10
console.log(findClosestId(100)); // undefined
```